Yellowstone geyser plugin - Client is not a constructor
I follow instruction from this repo example readme, but when I run
npm start -- --endpoint command, I got this error
Client is not a constructor
const client = new Client(args.endpoint, args.xToken, {"grpc.max_receive_message_length": 64 * 1024 * 1024, // 64MiB });

In client.ts file
What I can do right now, thanks for any support!
https://github.com/rpcpool/yellowstone-grpc/tree/master/examples/typescript
